STS 4.22.1 - EclEmma Code Coverage not showing
JaCoCo / EclEmma is not showing when I click on a project.
Previous STS4 version:
Version: 4.21.1.RELEASE
My current STS4 version:
Version: 4.22.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202405011620
Revision: 71bcc7a580385ea1ae7aa7af1ae8bef30aaea50a
I had updated my STS4 version via Check For Update under Help section.
The same problem arises in my team's STS4 IDE.
No Coverage option under Window -> Show View -> Other as well.
When clicked on a project, Coverage option is missing as well.
I just updated my STS4 version.
No Coverage option

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

related filed issue for the Spring Tools: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1259 - this needs some investigation from EclEmma maintainers. There is a package use constraint violation going on behind the scenes when installing EclEmma extension into Eclipse 2024-03 (and beyond probably) that is causing the extension to not work. I would recommend to reach out to the EclEmma extension maintainers for this.

For Eclipse 2024.03 EclEmma working again with manual installation the last version from github eclemma-3.1.9

Manual installation of the mentioned eclemma version worked! Thanks
